# Accessing main view from button in Custom TableViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uipickerview, uiactionsheet

I have a button in a table view cell which, when pressed brings up a UIPickerView. The only problem that I'm facing is finding out how to access the main view from inside the cell. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could follow the parent view chain up until you reach the view that is a UITableView. However, I think the better approach is to place the picker in the table cell. The metaphors here is pressing the button causes the cell to enter edit mode, and a picker view is needed (in your case). The whole table view API has plenty of helper functions to make that happen.

Comment: Thanks, but I managed to get it working with self.superview; Don't know if there's any reason why I shouldn't use this. Please tell me if there is. :)

Comment: That's essentially what I was suggesting, though I recommend that you always check the class of the superview to ensure it is the view layer you think it is.